# Remove class from a specific WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-5

I'm developing a WordPress theme in which I'm using Bootstrap as framework. I've designed the header as a sticky header with the .fixed-top class and now I need to remove this class in some specific pages by using the page id.

How can I do it? Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From your **header.php** file, inside the `<header>` tag, put a condition in the class attribute to add/remove your classes depending on the page.

### Ternary Operator

```php
<?= is_page(*) ? 'fixed-top' : ''; ?>
```

### If...else statement

```php
<?php if(is_page(*)){ echo 'fixed-top'; }?>
```

*Page ID, title, slug, or array of such to check against [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

---

See also :

- [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)
- [is_singular()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/)

Comment: Thank you @maiakd! the if...else statement works perfectly fine to stamp the class to a specific page. But how can I remove the class from a specific page? What can I write instead of echo?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. You can change the condition and adapt it the way you want. You can either use an `else {}` statement or do something like `if(!is_page(*))` to apply the class when it's not equal to this page and the ECHO is important here, it's used to output data to the screen.

Comment: I resolved thank to your last comment @maiakd. I've modified the code like this:
[code block]<?php if(is_page(3)){ echo 'regular-header'; }else{ echo 'fixed-top'; } ?>
In this mode I've replaced the .fixed-top class with the .regular-header class which I've created for the page who has the ID 3. Now it work perfectly fine.
Thank you very much!